# How to Access URL Parameter from Template File in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am using Iron Router, and I want to get the parameter from a URL and place it in my template file. For example:

> http://localhost:3000/categories/electronics

In my template file:

```
<template name="category_products">
     <p>Sorry, there are no _____ products.</p>
</template>
```

I want to replace `_____` with `electronics` so the output will be

> Sorry, there are no electronics products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've defined a route, you can get the parameters using `this.params`. You can also provide template with a data context that is an object that includes multiple keys:

```
Router.route('/categories/:name',()=>{
  this.render('category_products', {
    data: function () {
      return {
        cursor: Products.find({categoryName: this.params.name}),
        category: this.params.name
      };
    }
  });
});
```

html:

```
<template name="category_products">
  {{#if cursor.count()}}
    {{#each cursor}}
      {{name}}
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    <p>Sorry, there are no {{category}} products.</p>
  {{/endif}}
</template>
```